# Can array.some loop on an undefined?

Tags: javascript

---

I have a user that is generating Sentry reports from this code saying `Cannot read property 'values' of undefined`

```
var self = this;
if (self.queue()) {
    return self.queue().some(function (item, index) {
        return item.values[key] == value;
    });
} else {
    return false;
}
```

`self.queue()` is a knockout observable.
How is this possible? Does `array.some` loop through empty arrays?  Or is there some weirdness with observables that the `some` function is attached to the real array, and the array is being edited while it's being looped through?

The obvious answer is to do this

```
var self = this;
if (self.queue()) {
    return self.queue().some(function (item, index) {
        if (item && item.values) {
            return item.values[key] == value;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
} else {
    return false;
}
```

But I can't see a reason why I should have to do that.

Am I using the `some` function wrong? Do I need to duplicate the array first before I loop through it?

Thanks

-Edit

This test in node as per GMaiolo's example and Alexey Lebedev's comment

```
// let arr = [null, undefined, 0, 'something', undefined, 3]
let arr = [null, , , 'something', , 3]
console.log("test 1:");
for (const value of arr) {
    console.log(value)
}
console.log("\ntest 2:");
arr.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
console.log("\ntest 3:");
arr.some(function(item){
    console.log(item);
    return false;
});
```

Results

```
test 1:
null
undefined
undefined
something
undefined
3

test 2:
null
something
3

test 3:
null
something
3
```

Tested in node 8.11

Comment: It's also possible that the array contains things you dont think it does. `if (item) {` isn't going to stop your error. If `item` doesn't have a `values` property, or is `null`, same error

Comment: Good point, if one can happen, the other can too, I will edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `undefined` or `null` value it's still an array's element in its position, so, answering the particular question:

**Yes**, [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will loop over arrays filled with `undefined` elements.

---

That being said, we can test out what I've just said using [Array.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values):

```
let arr = [null, undefined, 0, 'something', undefined, 3]
const iterator = arr.values()

for (const value of iterator) {
  console.log(value) // output: null, undefined, 0, "something", undefined, 3
}
```

Comment: Well that's a game changer... the app has loops everywhere.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: but not on sparse elements.

Comment: What Nina said, `[1,,,2].some(x => console.log(x))` will not iterate over `undefined`'s in the middle.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev That doesn't appear to be entirely true for the example in the answer.  A `for (const value of arr) {` will loop through them, but a `arr.forEach(function(item){` and `arr.some(function(item){` will not.  I added my test code to my question. It's not directly relevant because the app uses forEach everywhere (es5 support) but it is interesting how the loops function differently.